# Mysql find phrase in Json array

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am looking for a way of find rows by given element of the json table that match the pattern.

Lets start with mysql table:

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `attributes` json DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `person` (`attributes`)
VALUES ('[{"scores": 1, "name": "John"},{"scores": 1, "name": "Adam"}]');

INSERT INTO `person` (`attributes`)
VALUES ('[{"scores": 1, "name": "Johny"}]');

INSERT INTO `person` (`attributes`)
VALUES ('[{"scores": 1, "name": "Peter"}]');
```

How to find all records where attributes[*].name consists `John*` pattern?

In the `John*` case the query should return 2 records (with John and Johny).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM `person`
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(`attributes`, '$[*].name') LIKE '%John%';
```

https://sqlize.online/s/P4

or

```
SELECT *
FROM `person`
WHERE `attributes` LIKE '%{"name": "John%';
```

https://sqlize.online/s/b4

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT person.*
FROM person
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(person.attributes, '$[*]' COLUMNS (name TEXT PATH '$.name')) parsed
WHERE parsed.name LIKE 'John%';
```

https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/c9e4a3ffa159c4be8c761d696e06d946/

Comment: Thanks @Akina. I use MariaDB 5.5 version and it seems that this query is not compatible with  my version. Do you know how fix the script to be compatible with 5.5?

Comment: @KeyB0rys MariaDB <> MySQL !!! Moreover, you use old version which have too poor instruments list implemented, and in general you need in iterative stored procedure. So "fix" is not possible, the solution must be completely rewrited, and it will be complex.